# Como ler um arquivo Json no php

Tags: php, json

```
{"acao":"muda-quantidade","dados":{"nova-quantidade":"2","referencia":"produto-um"}}
```

Eu estou aprendendo Json,e estou tentando ler um arquivo json no php e não estou conseguindo ler o segundo array, (dados), se alguem consegue me dar uma mão.

Comment: Como você está lendo poste o código?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primeiro de tudo esse seu json nao tem nenhum array.
Muito provavelmente vai chegar como string, ai e so usar o [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.json-decode.php)

```
$json = json_decode('{"acao":"muda-quantidade","dados":{"nova-quantidade":"2","referencia":"produto-um"}}');

$acao = $json->acao; //$acao agora tem o valor muda-quantidade
$dados = $json->dados;
$referencia = $dados->referencia; //$referencia agora tem o valor produto-um
//e por ai vai
```

Importante e que o retorno do `json_decode` no seu caso vai ser um `stdClass` que e uma classe generica por assim dizer.

Edit:
uma das suas propriedades do json esta com hifen `-`, nesse caso para obter o valor voce precisa fazer um cambalaxo `$dados->{'nova-quantidade'}`. Ou melhor ainda se puder, troca por algum caracter aceito em nome de variaveis.

Pra nao misturar demais as coisas nao vou dizer o por que de ser assim, mas pesquisa por: `variables variable` e `string interpolation`

Comment: é isso mesmo que preciso, mas pq quando coloco assim pra pegar a nova quantidade retorna 0

Comment: $dados = $lendo->dados;
 echo $dados->nova-quantidade;

Comment: Consegui descobrir o erro , por causa do sinal ( - ), no meio de nova-quantidade, da erro, retirando o sinal de ( - ), funciono, existe alguma forma de deixar o sinal ( - ) e ele interpretar e funcionar ?

Comment: @Danieldallacolletta editei a resposta, olha la

Comment: Opa, sim eu vi sua resposta , obrigado pela ótima ajuda, vou ver a melhor forma que eu possa adaptar ao meu projeto vou dar uma olhada sobre oque vc comentou  , variables variable e string interpolation.

Comment: se a resposta te ajudou marca ela como a melhor, assim voce tambem contribuiu para o site ^^